# Add dynamic buttons instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this to create additional buttons.

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    newVr += '<button type="button" class="abc">New</button>';
}
var parentDIV = document.getElementById('extraDIV');
parentDIV.innerHTML = newVr;
```

But this replaces the existing buttons in `parentDIV`. How do I add buttons instead of replacing the buttons?

Comment: `parentDIV.innerHTML += newVr`

Comment: @wZVanG thanks but I get an error `Syntax error, unrecognized expression:...` I'm using jQuery2.1.4

Comment: should `parentDIV.innerHTML += newVr;` this be inside the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `+` operator to concatenate strings. The [operator](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) `+=` means that the string is concatenated to the current value:

```js
var newVr = "";
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
  newVr += '<button type="button" class="abc">New</button>';
}
var parentDIV = document.getElementById('extraDIV');
parentDIV.innerHTML += newVr;
```

```html
<div id="extraDIV">
  <button>Old button</button>
  <button>Old button</button>
</div>
```

It works for me

Comment: this is another issue, it is impossible to see the error if you have not placed the code, you can make a new question so I can help

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use jQuery append:

> $("#extraDIV").append(newVr);

Note: For jQuery you need to add the link on the header something like:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
```